# JAVA, comparing two strings

Tags: java, string, compare

[EDITED} Ok I get it, let me reformulate. **numVol is 45** and the contents of the file is

```
54;a;23;c;de;56
23;d;24;c;h;456
45;87;c;y;535
432;42;h;h;543
```

but I still can't fix my problem, with this it return 543. so what im trying to do is return **line** when its equals **numVol** but check only the first number of a line.

---

I'm having trouble comparing two strings. Let's say I have a .csv file with the following content: `54;a;b;c;de` and that **numVol** value is 54. the method should be returning 54 but for some reason it doesnt enter in the "if" and it return "de".

```
public static String test(int numVol)throws Exception{
    File file = new File("test.csv");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    scanner.useDelimiter(";");
    String line = "";
    String sNumVol = ""+numVol; //create a string with numVol value in it
    while (scanner.hasNext()){
        line = scanner.next();
        if(line.equals(sNumVol)){
            scanner.close();
            return line;
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
    return line;
}
```

Comment: "ligne" is a typo, right? You mean to assign it to the "line" that you initialized before the loop?

Comment: yea my bad it's a type. ligne is actually line in french, I wanted to replace all the "ligne" to line so you cant can understand but i missed 1.

Comment: Works fine for me. Looks like it is the file.

Comment: when it reads '54' from the file is it definitely 54 i.e. no whitespace etc? it may be better to read it in as an int rather then converting the arg to a string.

Comment: Try putting `System.out.println(line)` in the loop after the assignment to see what it prints out.

Comment: Check your file, this seems to work for me as well. I confirmed it by putting a println call in the if block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that now that you've told `Scanner` to use `;` as a delimiter, it's *not* using whitespace as a delimiter anymore. So the token being tested against `"45"` isn't `"45"`, it's `"456\n45"` (the end of the previous line, the newline, and the beginning of the next line), which isn't a match.

Change your `useDelimiter` line to use *both* semicolons and whitespace as your delimiters:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("[;\\s]");
```

...and then the scanner sees the `"456"` and the `"45"` separately, and matches the `"45"`.

This code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Parse {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String result = test(45);
            System.out.println("result = " + result);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }
    }

    public static String test(int numVol)throws Exception{
        File file = new File("test.csv");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        scanner.useDelimiter("[;\\s]"); // <==== Change is here
        String line = "";
        String sNumVol = ""+numVol;
        while (scanner.hasNext()){
            line = scanner.next();
            if(line.equals(sNumVol)){
                scanner.close();
                return line;
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
        return line;
    }
}
```

With this `test.csv`:

```
54;a;23;c;de;56
23;d;24;c;h;456
45;87;c;y;535
432;42;h;h;543
```

Shows this:

```
$ java Parse
result = 45
```

---

The way to find the answer to this problem was simply to walk through the code with a debugger and watch the value of `line`, or (if for some reason you don't have a debugger?!), insert a `System.out.println("line = " + line);` statement into the loop to see what was being compared. For instance, if you insert a `System.out.println("line = " + line);` above the `line = scanner.next();` line above and you just use `";"` as the delimiter:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Parse {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String result = test(45);
            System.out.println("result = " + result);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }
    }

    public static String test(int numVol)throws Exception{
        File file = new File("test.csv");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        scanner.useDelimiter(";"); // <== Just using ";"
        String line = "";
        String sNumVol = ""+numVol;
        while (scanner.hasNext()){
            line = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("line = [[" + line + "]]");
            if(line.equals(sNumVol)){
                scanner.close();
                return line;
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
        return line;
    }
}
```

You see this:

```
$ java Parse
line = [[54]]
line = [[a]]
line = [[23]]
line = [[c]]
line = [[de]]
line = [[56
23]]
line = [[d]]
line = [[24]]
line = [[c]]
line = [[h]]
line = [[456
45]]
line = [[87]]
line = [[c]]
line = [[y]]
line = [[535
432]]
line = [[42]]
line = [[h]]
line = [[h]]
line = [[543
]]
result = 543
```

...which helps visualize the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, I actually found the answer after Varun Madiath and Marco told me that the code worked but I still didn't know what to add to the delimiter to make it work, im really new coding. all i need now is to make it only check the first number of a line. thanks

Comment: @BobJ: You're welcome! We were all new to it once, and (for what it's worth) this was non-obvious, the human brain naturally breaks up those CSV lines and sees the `45` on its own, even though the code (naturally) doesn't. The key here really is walking through it with a debugger and seeing what the code is seeing. It's amazing how often doing that makes something obvious. Netbeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA, or even just JSwat, they all let us walk through code step-by-step...